# How to get first n characters from another column that doesn't contain specific characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

| ID | product name |
| --- | --- |
| 1BJM10 | 1BJM10_RS2022_PK |
|  | L_RS2022_PK |
|  | 2PKL10_RS2022_PK |
|  | 3BDG10_RS2022_PK |
| 1BJM10 | 1BJM10_RS2022_PK |

My desired output is like this

| ID | product name |
| --- | --- |
| 1BJM10 | 1BJM10_RS2022_PK |
| - | L_RS2022_PK |
| 2PKL10 | 2PKL10_RS2022_PK |
| 3BDG10 | 3BDG10_RS2022_PK |
| 1BJM10 | 1BJM10_RS2022_PK |

2nd row shouldn't get the ID because is has "_" in the product name's first 6 characters.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work

```
df.loc[df['ID'].isna()] = df['ID'].fillna(~df['product name'].str[:6].contains("_"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain both conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` with helper `Series`:

```
s = df['product name'].str[:6]
df.loc[df['ID'].isna() & ~s.str.contains("_"), 'ID'] = s
print (df)
       ID      product name
0  1BJM10  1BJM10_RS2022_PK
1     NaN       L_RS2022_PK
2  2PKL10  2PKL10_RS2022_PK
3  3BDG10  3BDG10_RS2022_PK
4  1BJM10  1BJM10_RS2022_PK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['ID'] = df['product name'].apply(lambda x: x[:x.find('_')] if x.find('_')>=6 else '')
```